# google plus activities search query format

Tags: api, google-plus

Do you know what is a format of query in activities:search  api method. Can I use more some kind of disjunction, conjunction or phrases?

Comment: I see it uses OR as or and " " as AND. So it works using: word1 OR word3 ... or word1 word2 word3. But when I try to mix it like word1 OR word2 OR (word3 word4) it does not work correctly. It looks like it wants to AND word4 with all other keywords